# What is the significance of a large く character in literary texts?

Tags: grammar, meaning, etymology, history

I am currently reading an early story by Tanizaki Junichiro in Japanese. I have come across both the hiragana く　and ぐ written twice the size they usually are, taking up the same amount of space on the page as two characters. Is there any significance in this?

These include words such as ひい**く**と and いろ**く**の注文, where the character in bold is written at twice the height as normal.

Any help would be most appreciated (^-^)

Comment: I think your question is wrong. What you are probably mentioning are not hiragana.

Comment: @sawa. But it is valid if it was mistaken for hiragana.

Comment: It would be helpful if a picture of the area in question were included.

Answer (score 15):

It's a [repetition mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark#Kana) or `くの字点` (for its similarity to the character く, as you noted).

> い
>   ろ
>    〳
>   〵
>   の
>   注
>   文

It's only used in vertical text, and repeats over two or more characters, which for your examples results in `ひいひいと` and `いろいろの注文`.

There is also a single-kana repetition mark `ゝ` (which is the kana equivalent of the kanji repetition mark `々`), but just like the multi-character version, it's no longer used in modern Japanese.

I don't want to retype the whole Wikipedia article, so do click on that link ;)